# How do I get Calendar to appear as a Service Provider after updating to Solspace Freeform 5

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform

I have updated Freeform from version 4 to 5 and have a few questions. But the first is related to getting the Forms Connected to the Calendar.

With Freeform 4 we had them connected using Element Connections. It appears that version 5 has great new features. However, we don't see the option of Calendar to select and create the Element connections this new way.

The only options appear to be Entry and User. Any help appreciated.

[image]